# How should I read this code about recursion?

Tags: function, recursion

How should I read this code?

```
  if n <= 0:
    return ''  
  else:
    temp = repeatStar(n-1)  
    s = '*'  + temp 
    return s

a = 4
res = repeatStar(a)
print(res)
```

The part where I don't understand it anymore is the repeatStar(n-1) part. It will repeat the function until the n == 0 and then returns ''. But then where do all the stars come from? s = '*' + temp. So that should be '*' + '' right? What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if I didn't explain it well

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way, running this you always see that the number of stars is equal to the input value.

Why is that?

Lets walk through the case you provided where the input is 4:

you call the function with input n = 4, it checks the if statement, then goes to the else block, initializing temp, it tries to compute 'repeatStar(4-1)'

> you call the function with input n = 3, it checks the if statement, then goes to the else block, initializing temp, it tries to compute 'repeatStar(3-1)'
>
> > you call the function with the input n = 2, it checks the if statement, then goes to the else block, initializing temp, it tries to compute 'repeatStar(2-1)'
> >
> > > you call the function with the input n = 1, it checks the if statement, then goes to the else block, initializing temp, it tries to compute 'repeatStar(1-1)'
> > >
> > > > you call the function with the input n = 0, it checks the if statement then goes to the return empty_string
> > >
> > > now having temp as (empty_string), s is assigned ('*' + empty_string) and returns that
> >
> > now having temp as ('*' + empty_string), s is assigned ('*' + '*' + empty_string) and returns that
>
> now having temp as ('*' + '*' + empty_string'), s is assigned ('*' + '*' + '*' + empty_string') and returns that

now having temp as ('*' + '*' + '*' + empty_string'), s is assigned ('*' + '*' + '*' + '*' + empty_string')

Now the stack is emptied and we print the result '****'